# Magit v2.2.0 failed to load: wrong type argument

Tags: magit, install

After updating to magit v2.2.0 (and removing the old `magit`, `git-rebase-mode` and `git-commit-mode` I got the following error message after calling `M-x magit-status`:

```
Wrong type argument: symbolp, (cyg . win)
```

and Magit does not fire up. Thought it could come from my init file but removing it did not solve the problem.

`M-x magit-version` gives Magit 20151019.443, Git 2.6.2, Emacs 24.4.1.

OS: Ubuntu 15.04

Any hints? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Magit package on Melpa ("non-stable") depends on version `2.11.0` of Dash and that versions (i.e. snapshot) strings on Melpa have the form `YYYYMMDD.SSSS`, which is always larger than `2.MM.SS`.

I'll fix that, but meanwhile you can just install the most recent Dash version explicitly.

Comment: Works now after installing dash (`M-x list-packages` and then choosing dash). Tx!

Comment: FWIW, the latest Dash snapshot is now also available from [GNU-devel ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/dash.html) whose version strings are different from MELPA's and don't share the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recent magit updates broke compatibility with older versions.

The easiest way to fix it is to remove it from your `.emacs.d`:

```
rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/elpa/magit*
```

Restart your Emacs and install Magit again and everything should be fine.

Comment: Still not working. After re-installing Magit, the compile-log gives the following message:
`In toplevel form:
magit-git.el:535:36:Error: Wrong type argument: sequencep, win`

`In end of data:
magit-mode.el:1086:1:Warning: the function `-non-nil' is not known to be
    defined.`

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue here.

Comment: helped me after magit broke after updating all packages. thanks!